# Add new case: "Case Type is a required field"

Tags: civicase, 4.6

When I try (on 4.6.18) to create a new Case, I get an error saying Case Type and Case Start Date are required, but no fields exist on the form to specify these?

I have Case Types defined and enabled at `civicrm/a/#/caseType` and I've tried adding a case from the menu *Cases » New Case* and from the Cases tab.

[image: screenshot]

There's no javascript errors showing, nothing in Drupal's watchdog log. Hmmm. Am I doing something daft?

Answer (score 3):

This was due to permissions in the `templates_c` folder. Some entries in there were not deletable by the user that Apache was running as. I discovered this by attempting to clear caches at `civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1` which generated lots of errors.

Removing these files/or correcting their permissions and clearing the cache fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recognize this problem, but I am assuming you have an extension active on the form too? If so, sure that does not muck things up?

Comment: Think it's just a custom field group for all activities. Will disable and check

Comment: yeah same behaviour when the custom field group is disabled.